# Socket.io клиент на Android не подключается к серверу на Node.js

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, express, socket.io

Есть сервер из [примера](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/), прослушивает порт 27018 
    Вот код сервера:

```
var app = require("express")();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
n=27018;

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    console.log('-------');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');

  });
      socket.on("chat message", function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg)
  });
});

http.listen(n, function(){
  console.log("listening on *:"+n);
});
```

Вот клиент

```
package a41.a13.a4.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket mSocket;
    TextView Exep;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Exep = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);}


    public void Connect(View v){
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.100.3:27018");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e)
        {
            Exep.setText(e.toString());
        }
        mSocket.connect();
};
```

Проблема в том что клиент подключается только на локальный айпи (на сервере срабатывает эвент `Connection`), а на внешний ip не подключается. 
Но если попытаться подключиться через браузер на смартфоне то всё подключается( и на внешний и на локальный ip)

 Значит проблема в клиенте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден) роутер сбрасывал подключение когда соединение шло из локальной сети( даже если обращаться на внешний ip)
Грубо говоря в локальной сети не работали правила port forwarding, а из интернета всё работает прекрасно.Модель роутера Huawei HG8245H.

а в браузере на смартфоне работало потому что там был аналог функции Opera Turbo, подключение через прокси(ускорение загрузки страниц, удаление рекламы и т.д.), браузер UC Browser.